# Turn variable name into string inside function dplyr

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyeval

I'm doing something kinda simple, but tidyeval always puzzles me. In this case, I have a function that plots something and I want to also save it afterwards using the name of the column I'm plotting, something like this:

```
bar_plot= function(table, col_plot){
    ggplot(table, aes(x=region,
                    y= {{col_plot}})) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill="steelblue") +
     ggsave(glue('results/{col_plot}.png'))
  
}
```

The plot has no problems, but I'm not able to save it (doesn't find the object, because it isn't reading it as a string). Tried using `quo`, `enquo`, `sym`, and nothing worked. What is the way to turn my variable name into a string inside the function?

For reproducibility this is enough:

```
df = data.frame(region = c(1, 2), mean_age = c(20, 30))
```

Thanks !

Comment: Do you just need to put ggsave in a new line without the + from the previous line?

Comment: That won't solve the variable problem, though, it still won't compute as a string

Comment: @danh It saves the plot as `'results/{col_plot}.png'` not as `'results/mean_age.png'` like OP wants.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas are you sure? It saves just fine as `results/mean_age.png` for me.

Comment: Sorry, I think OP wants to call the function with unquoted names, e.g., `bar_plot(df, mean_age)`. In that case, the `ggsave` line gives an error `object 'mean_age' not found`.

Comment: Gotcha.  Yeah I was assuming he wanted to call the function with a quoted column name:  In which case his ggplot call should be: `ggplot(table, aes(x=region, y=.data[[col_plot]]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abstracting out the plotting part and focusing on the file name, I think you can also use `rlang::as_name` here to convert the symbol into the string you need.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(region = c(1, 2), mean_age = c(20, 30))

bar_plot <- function(table, col_plot) {
  # ggplot(table, aes(
  #   x = region,
  #   y = {{ col_plot }}
  # )) +
  #   geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "steelblue")
  filename <- glue::glue("results/{rlang::as_name(enquo(col_plot))}.png")
  filename
}

bar_plot(df, mean_age)
#> results/mean_age.png
```

Note that we need to do two things: first wrap the argument `col_plot` in `enquo`, so we get `mean_age` of instead of literally `col_plot`. Then convert with `as_name()` to turn `mean_age` into `"mean-age"`.

Comment: Thank you! seems a bit more intuitive than deparse + substitute

Comment: With rlang 1.0 you can write `rlang::englue("results/{{ col_plot }}.png")`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```r
bar_plot <- function(table, col_plot) {
  
  p <- ggplot(table, aes(region, {{col_plot}})) + geom_col(fill = "steelblue")
  
  ggsave(paste0('results/', deparse(substitute(col_plot)), '.png'), p)
  
}

bar_plot(df, mean_age)
```

So you have:

**./results/mean_age.png**

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Was harder than expected. Is there a more straightforward way if my function takes the variable name as string as an argument, instead of the variable name without quotes? can I do something like `.data[[col_plot]]` in the ggplot call if it's a string?

Comment: You can use `aes_string` instead of `aes` to pass a string

Comment: @JuanC yes, since ggplot2 version 3.0 `.data[[col_plot]]` is a good way to use a string column name in ggplot. `aes_string` is soft-deprecated. This is also the way [its recommended to use ggplot in packages](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html).

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I'm clear now! I'll use strings, seems more understandable to me